# Catch error in Angular 2

Tags: angular, try-catch

I trying to catch errors in http post, but it's showing this error:

TypeError: error.json is not a function

I didn't find anything on google.

I followed the example on Angular.io site.

[image]

My code:

```
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

//import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class EmpresasCrudService {


    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

  //  public allItems;
   // public _qtd;

     postHttpEmpresas(endpoint_url, data): Observable<Response> {
         let body = JSON.stringify(data);

         let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json' });
         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post(endpoint_url, body, options)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

EDIT:
when I put:

```
postHttpEmpresas(endpoint_url, data): Observable<Response> {
         let body = JSON.stringify(data);

         let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json' });
         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post(endpoint_url, body, options)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
    }

private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
    try {
        errMsg = error.json();
    } catch (e) {
        // No content response..
        errMsg = null;
    }
}
    console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

it's showing the error in console.log but until give me a error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Response#json()` will throw an error if response does not have a body (status 204 - No Content response for example). If you don't know whether the error response has a body or not, a way to go would be to try/catch extracting the response content as follows:

```
if (error instanceof Response) {
    try {
        body = error.json();
    } catch (e) {
        // No content response..
        body = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edit my question with the result of your answer... I don't know if i'm doing right

Comment: Yes, that's the concept I was pointing to. Do you still see your error? Btw you shouldn't have updated your original question, can you return the original question so the original context is kept for future users?

Comment: Also, error.json() will return a body object, I guess you need something like : let mssg = error.json().error;, or maybe: let mssg = error.json().errorMessage; ?

Comment: I put this 2 ways and, error:
TypeError: error.json is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._error (empresas-create.component.ts:300)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:223)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:184)
    at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.js:77)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)

Comment: I don't know what to do

Comment: Can u post your 'handleError' funtion here in comments?

Comment: This is the handle of my question:        'private handleError (error: Response | any) {     // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure     let errMsg: string;     if (error instanceof Response) {       const body = error.json() || '';       const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);       errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;     } else {       errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();     }     console.error(errMsg);     return Observable.throw(errMsg);   }'

Comment: Replace your 'handleError' funtion with this one: "    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;if (error instanceof Response) {try {let body = error.json() || {};let err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}: ${err}`;} catch (e) {let err = 'Server error...';errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}: ${err}`;}} else {errMsg = JSON.stringify(error || '');}console.log('Handled error message: ', errMsg);return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }". Let me know if you still see the error after applying it.

Comment: *I did how you said me, but, the same error:*
`ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
TypeError: error.json is not a function`

Comment: If you just ignore your handleError function, and in the catch block just say: .`catch(err => Observable.throw('Unknown error occurred...'));`, will the error be thrown in that case as well?

Comment: I'm not understanding ... I put this way and return the same error :/
TypeError: error.json is not a function

Comment: Then the problem isn't in the service you've posted in your question at all. Can you provide the component's code where you're subscribing to this Observable?

Comment: emperases-create.component.ts maybe ?

Comment: the problem was in empresas-create.component.ts... I was calling a old function that I made for test ... I fixed it and works fine like my question ... sorry the 
inconvenient